# How to select histogram-like on sql?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, histogram

I have the following table `messages`:

```
destination_number | message_text | pk/sender_number/metadata/timestamps/other_stuff
123                | hi           | ...
456                | at 4         | ...
123                | how are you? | ...
123                | I'm David    | ...
456                | please       | ...
789                | no           | ...
789                | stop         | ...
012                | exit         | ...
```

doing `select count(1) as quantity, destination_number from messages group by destination_number` I got:

```
quantity | destination_number
3        | 123
2        | 456
2        | 789
1        | 012
```

now I would like almost an histogram:

```
quantity | quantity_of_numbers_that_received_that_quantity
3        | 1                      // only number 123 received 3 messages
2        | 2                      // numbers 456 and 789 received 2 messages
1        | 1                      // only 012 received 1 message
```

my question is: what query would bring this last table directly from `messages`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, use a second level of aggregation:

```
select quantity, count(*)
from (select count(1) as quantity, destination_number
      from messages
      group by destination_number
     ) m
group by quantity
order by quantity;
```

I would typically include something like `min(destination_number), max(destination_number)` to see sample values as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
select quantity, count(destination_number) as quantity_of_numbers_that_received_that_quantity
from (
  select count(1) as quantity, destination_number 
  from messages 
  group by destination_number
)
group by quantity
```